# Initialising dictionary like class

Tags: python, dictionary, initialization

```
class fileInfo(dict):
    def __init__(self, name, typ, size = 1):
        self = {}
        self["name"] = name
        self["type"] = typ
        self["size"] = size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == "name":
            return dict.__getitem__(self, "name")+ "." + dict.__getitem__(self, "type")
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
```

I have created this class, but I have problems with the **init** function.
When I try to initialize an object of this class, the **init** function returns me an empty dictionary.

What am I not understanding as far as the initialization function is concerned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
    self = {}
```

That line creates a new object of type `dict`, and binds the local name `self` to it. This is wholly unrelated to the previous value of `self`, which is lost. And, since `self` is a local variable, the object created by this line will be marked for deletion when `__init__()` returns.

Try this instead:

```
super(fileInfo, self).__init__()
```

This neither creates nor destroys any objects, but modifies the object referred to by `self`.

Reference:

- [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)
- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Exaclty. `self = {}` just changed the meaning of `self` within `__init__`, so it no longer referred to the actual *self*, but to a new dict instead.

Comment: I understand now that I need to use super, but could you explain what `self = {}` does?

Comment: You don't even need to call `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @L3viathan - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Robᵩ Since we're subclassing `dict`, it is not necessary to call the `__init__` method of the superclass; it will behave like a dictionary anyways.

Comment: @L3viathan - do you have some support for that? Is that behavior documented? I can imagine a `dict` implementation that would require `__init__()` to be called.

Comment: @Robᵩ OPs example [just works without](https://repl.it/D9nF/0). Of course there are cases where you want to call `__init__()`, e.g. when you're preinitializing it from keyword arguments. This is no special behaviour, just the fact that `dict.__init__` doesn't do anything special if you give it no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method of any class is called once you create an instance of the class. You can't call it manually to instantiate the class, but use the class name.

Also, you are not really initializing a class that inherits it's methods and properties from `dict`. You need to use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) for that. Also, this is a case where calling `__init__` makes actual sense.

```
class fileInfo(dict):
    def __init__(self, name, typ, size = 1):
        super(fileInfo, self).__init__()

        self["name"] = name
        self["type"] = typ
        self["size"] = size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == "name":
            return dict.__getitem__(self, "name")+ "." + dict.__getitem__(self, "type")
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

file_info = fileInfo("file-name", "txt", 100)

print file_info["name"]
```

Output:

```
file-name.txt
```